# Which directories should be on the same filesystem as the root "/" filesystem?

Tags: fhs

I read [an article](https://opensource.com/life/16/10/introduction-linux-filesystems) and it states that "bin" "dev" "etc" "lib" "root" "sbin" directories should be in the same filesystem as the root directory, that is, they should not be mounted as a separate filesystem.

I'm a little confused, for example, in many distributions now the "sbin" "bin" and "lib" directories are symbolic linked to the "usr" directory.

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Apr 30 18:19 bin -> usr/bin
...
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     7 Apr 30 18:19 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 Apr 30 18:19 lib32 -> usr/lib32
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     9 Apr 30 18:19 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    10 Apr 30 18:19 libx32 -> usr/libx32
...
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     8 Apr 30 18:19 sbin -> usr/sbin
```

However, the article does not specify that the "/" directory and the usr directory must be on the same filesystem. I've also looked at the previous questions, but I'm still confused. Which directories must be in the same filesystem and which should we keep in separate filesystems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current line of thought is that `/usr` should be integrated to `/`, and a few distributions simply symlink `/bin`,`/sbin`,`/lib` to the equivalents in `/usr` as you saw. E.g. [Debian, which will only support merged `/usr` starting with the next release (*bookworm*)](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge), and [Fedora appears to have done the merge in Fedora 17, already in 2012](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove).

Basically, the arguments to that seem to boil down to

- it's the job if `initramfs` to bring the system to a usable state anyway, so no need for *another* "minimal" system to do that
- the split doesn't really work anyway, since programs installed in `/usr/bin` may depend on libraries in `/lib`, so they aren't totally independent anyway
- the whole idea of the split is a historical accident that just kept going after the original reasons had turned irrelevant.

The `/` filesystem isn't that minimal anyway, e.g. on one dated pre-merge system, I have a bit less than 600 MB of files in `/bin`, `/sbin` and `/lib`, and a bit more than 600 MB in `/usr`. (No X or GUI stuff there, though.) On another system, `/usr` is a bit bigger, at around 2 GB, but even that is not remotely an issue with current storage sizes. At the same time, the initramfs files are about 15 MB, which is smaller enough that it might matter, and the initramfs doesn't have stuff like `/etc` that needs to be modifiable so it can be semi-statically installed.

Looking at the same system, the split of utilities between `/bin` and `/usr/bin` also seems a bit arbitrary, e.g. `sh` and `bash` are in `/bin` (obviously), and so is `grep`, but e.g. `awk`, `head`, `wc` and `zsh` are in `/usr/bin`. Not that modern systems rely that much on shell scripts to boot, and it's only the stuff that's needed to mount the remaining filesystem, that need to use the more limited set of tools, but anyway. And an administrator who likes zsh might not be happy if they were unable to log in when there's an issue with the filesystem...

The story about the origins of the split seems to be this:

> When the [original Unix system, in early 1970s] grew too big to fit on the first RK05 disk pack (their
> root filesystem) they let it leak into the second one, which is where all the
> user home directories lived (which is why the mount was called /usr).  They
> replicated all the OS directories under there (/bin, /sbin, /lib, /tmp...) and
> wrote files to those new directories because their original disk was out of
> space.

(From Rob Landley, on Busybox mailing lists, [Understanding the bin, sbin, usr/bin , usr/sbin split](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2010-December/074114.html), edited slightly. The same message discusses the matter in a lot more detail.)

The systemd folks have also written some thoughts on that:

- ["Booting Without /usr is Broken"](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/separate-usr-is-broken/), and
- ["The Case for the /usr Merge"](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/)

Answer (score 2):

The /bin vs /usr/bin issue is an old issue. The idea was to have a really subset of the operating system able to mount a /usr partition if you happened to separate them. This can help with old PC BIOS with sector number limitations which makes you choose a very small / partition.

Nowadays, the distinction is no more pertinent. Linux puts all things needed to load the OS in an initramfs little archive which can be loaded by Grub and many of its fancy modules if needed (you can also have a simple plain separated /boot partition).